# finding the frequency of CAN send and CAN receive messages using CAN in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, can

Can anyone please share me the command how can i find the frequency of CAN send and CAN receive messages. I'm sending CAN messages using a serial port and receiving it with a peak CAN usb. There is no error no drop messages between both receving and sending sides but i don't know the command to get the frequency. I'm using only simple candump and can send commands in Ubuntu. I know the bps but i want to know the frequency of sending and receiving sides. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`candump` can output the timestamp for each message in different formats. Check the usage notes of candump.

`candump -t d can0` will give you the time difference between messages for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output to [wc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_%28Unix%29) with the `-l` flag for line counting:

```
candump can0 | wc -l
```